# How do I check what is in my iCloud Music Library?

Tags: music, apple-music

I wanted to switch my Apple Store country but I got a warning that I have an iCloud music library that will be lost if I switch countries. But I looked in the music app at “My Library” and there weren’t any songs in there. Where can I see what is in my iCloud music library?

Comment: If you know there's no songs in there then what are you worried about?  The warning is a standard warning Apple shows.  You can search here and see the questions about it.